# android studio huge file: android.value.resources.index

Tags: android-studio

Android Studio 1.3 on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine takes up a lot of space because of a file called **android.value.resources.index.values** (size 3.9 GB) in the directory **.AndroidStudio1.3/system/index/android.value.resources.index**

Do you know what this file does and if I can just delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you open the file in Notepad, you'll find that it is an index for the ids and strings generated from the Android projects.
I think it should be safe to delete, since it is recreated once the project/module is opened again by Android Studio. I deleted mines on Android 1.4.1 and the files were recreated with much smaller size.

Answer (score 1):

**It's safe to delete**

Just wanted to confirm it with you, I have 3 laptops using different versions of Android Studio v1.4, 1.5 as well as in 2.x.